# Excel - COUNTIF and SUMIF across multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I have a sheet with multiple columns of "Yes" / "No". I need to count the number of rows that have >5 "Yes". Obviously determining if an individual row should be included is easy using countif, but I can't figure out how to make the row 'eligible to be counted' and then sum the number of rows that meet my criteria.

Comment: Create a helper colum that will count if Yes... Btw, if you post your data we can help you. Or at least an image of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Use a helper column of countifs() for each row.  Then at the bottom use another countif that counts all those >5.  Or create a UDF with vba that does what you want.

Comment: Oh man. Duh. Thank you!

Is there a way to do it without the helper column - just for my excel knowledge. I'm guessing there is a way to do it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: There are ways to do this with a single formula - assuming the columns are adjacent, i.e. in one range - see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your range is `A2:Z100` this array formula will count the number of rows with 5 or more `"Yes"` entries

`=SUM((MMULT((A2:Z100="Yes")+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:Z100)^0))>=5)+0)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or you can use this version with `FREQUENCY`

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:Z100="Yes",ROW(A2:Z100)),ROW(A2:Z100))>=5,1))`

....which also needs "array entry"

or a third approach with `COUNTIF` - **doesn't** need array entry

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2:Z100,ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2),0,1),"Yes")>=5))`

Comment: I think he wants only rows with >5 "Yes" values. Otherwise that looks awesome.

Comment: You are probably right, Jacob, obviously you can change the >=5 as required